# jquery execute function when two conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I need to execute a specific function `mvFinishItUp()` when two conditions are met. More specifically, one condition is the callback success of a `$.ajax` the other is a normal flow of the code until it reaches the function. Kinda of this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: mv_finalUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        mvFinishItUp(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});

/* here a lot more code, with animations and some delays */

mvFinishItUp(data) {
    /* My function code */
    /* But this code must only run after it has been called via the call back
       and after all the other code has been ran as well */
}
```

So, the function must wait for all the code if the ajax callback is quicker, or the other way around. Any ideas on how this could be implemented?

I'm willing to change the whole concept of script code, as I believe the loose code between the ajax, and the function itself should go to a function aswell ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [jQuery Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Remove the `success:` parameter from the AJAX call, and register the handler later:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(...); 

// do some other synchronous stuff
...

// and *then* register the callback
jqxhr.done(mvFinishItUp);
```

Deferred objects cope perfectly well (by design) with being registered on an AJAX event *after* that event already finished.

Comment: I don't think you understood his question or may be I am not.. Read his comments in the below post

Comment: @Vega I believe I have understood the question perfectly.

Comment: I am curious to know what would happen if `jqxhr.done(mvFinishItUp);` is executed after success callback. Meaning his ajax code is quicker than his function code and success callback is done before it could reach `.done`

Comment: @alnitak is on the right track here...  seems to me that your other code needs to be in a custom deferred function.   read through the jquery api for `$.when()`

Comment: True... although Vega solution will almost for sure work out, this seems a more proper approach to the problem. It just takes more time on studying deferred objects ;)

Comment: @Vega _there is no success callback_ - this takes the place of `success:` and only registers the callback _after_ the other code is done.

Comment: @Eduardo this is one of the canonical use cases for deferred objects - they're _really_ worth learning how to use properly!

Comment: @Alnitak my bad.. what I meant was ajax call completed before you could really register the callback.

Comment: @Alnitak this is definitely something worth looking at. I have too many questions right now, but I believe google will help on those. Thanks for pointing out the right direction. Will accept as soon as I figure all out :)

Comment: @Eduardo  google will help, as will stackoverflow - there's quite a few questions about deferred objects here now! ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak sure will. Basically when I `var jqxhr = $.ajax(...);` the ajax functions starts doing it's stuff right? When I register the callback, it might already be completed, right?

Comment: @Eduardo yes, exactly.  And if it has, the callback will start executing immediately.

Comment: @GabrielJürgens it's nothing a few minutes reading the jQuery manual wouldn't produce - these have been available for over a year now... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here I add an second parameter to check callback check

```
 function mvFinishItUp(data, byCallback) {

    var iscallback = byCallback || false; // if you don't send byCallback
                                          // default will false
    if(iscallback) {
       // execute if called by callback
    }
 }

 success: function (data) {
        mvFinishItUp(data, true); // call with second parameter true
 },
```

To execute `mvFinishItUp()` after ajax done and all codes between ajax and `mvFinishItUp` finished you can do something like this:

```
var allFunctionExecuted = false; // global to detect all code execution

$.ajax({
    url: mv_finalUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        mvFinishItUp(data, true);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});

function func1() {

}

function func2() {

}

// some other code

function func3() {
    allFunctionExecuted = true;
}
```

Now,

```
 function mvFinishItUp(data, byCallback) {

    var iscallback = byCallback || false; // if you don't send byCallback
                                          // default will false

    if(iscallback && allFunctionExecuted) {

       // execute if ajax done
       // and others code done
    }
 }
```

Comment: but what if the `$.ajax`callback is faster the the whole rest of code, my mvFinishItUp will be called before the rest of the code (the second criteria for it to be executed), right ?

Comment: @Eduardo What is this _rest of the code_ you are talking about? It is easier because `$.ajax` has a callback.. but how can we determine the end of _rest of the code_

Comment: @Vega the whole code in between the `$.ajax` function and the final `mvFinishItUp` function. Basically `mvFinishItUp` can only be executed when the ajax and the whole rest of the code are all completed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
var _data = undefined;

$.ajax({
    url: mv_finalUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        _data = data;
        myFinishItUp(data); // call the function from here if it's faster
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});

/* here a lot more code, with animations and some delays */

function myFinishItUp(data) {
    this.data = data; // store the data from the AJAX call or the code, whichever reaches first 
                      // if the code reaches this before the AJAX call completes, data will be undefined
    if(typeof this.wasCalled == "undefined") {
        /* My function code */
        /* But this code must only run after it has been called via the call back
           and after all the other code has been ran as well */
        this.wasCalled = true;
    }
}(_data); // function that calls itself when the code gets to this point with a self-contained boolean variable to keep track of whether it has already been called
```

I used a self calling function execute when the code flow gets to that point, but if it's called from the AJAX call, it won't execute. It keeps track of whether or not it's already been called with a self-contained boolean value.

Comment: and if the `$.ajax` function is the first one to call the `mvFinishItUp` after, when the code reached itself the variable `data` will still be set ?

Comment: No, but we can change that. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, (It is just psuedo code)

```
var isAJAXDone = false, isFunctionCodeDone = false;
$.ajax({
  //..
  success: function () {
     isAJAXDone = true;
     mvFinishItUp(data, isAJAXDone, isFunctionCodeDone);
  } 
});

//..Your function code
//..Add this below the last line before the function ends
isFunctionCodeDone = true;
mvFinishItUp(data, isAJAXDone, isFunctionCodeDone);


//..
mvFinishItUp(data, isAJAXDone, isFunctionCodeDone ) {
   if (isAJAXDone && isFunctionCodeDone) {
      //Do your magic
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very "ugly" code, but you can modify it to not use global vars, so this is just illustrative:

```
var ajaxExecuted = false,
    codeExecuted = false;

$.ajax({
    url: mv_finalUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        ajaxExecuted = true;
        mvFinishItUp(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});

/* here a lot more code, with animations and some delays */
codeExecuted = true;

mvFinishItUp(data) {
    /* My function code */
    if(ajaxExecuted && codeExecuted) {
      /* But this code must only run after it has been called via the call back
         and after all the other code has been ran as well */
    }
}
```

I just added two flags: ajaxExecuted and codeExecuted, and inside the function an if statement that checks the value of the those flags, and executes only when the two of them are set to true. So no mather who calls it first, it get only executed when the two flags are set to true.

A cleaner way could be to implement the function in an object, and use properties instead of global vars.

Comment: no, the cleaner, jQuery way is to use a deferred object... ;-)

Comment: I agree, I was just reading your answer, and is much better than mine, so, one more vote to yours! thanks!