# AJAX launch final asyc call when multiple asyc calls are complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm thinking about how to better manage the order of running multiple async calls to achieve the best turnaround time. Basically the process is like this：
When the webpage starts loading it shows the page and launches several AJAX calls a(),b(),and c(). After these three are all finished, run async call d(). I checked several threads like [jquery execute function when two conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852561/jquery-execute-function-when-two-conditions-are-met) but that's not quite the same.

I tried to use multiple flags showing whether the async call is complete and one block function to block the process till it's ok to shoot the last call.

```
var aFinished=false;
function a() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller:'environment', action:'a')}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true
      }).done(function(jsonData) {
          //do something
          aFinished=true;
    });
}
//same flag+function for b() and c()
function d(){
    blockTillAllDone();
    var jsonData=$.ajax(...).done(...);
}
function blockTillAllDone(){
    if(aFinished&&bFinished&&cFinished){
        console.log("Ok to continue");
        return;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Have to wait");
        setTimeout(blockTillAllDone(),2000);
    }
}
a();b();c();d();
```

The performance was not really good because  of the growing stack caused by recursive block function. Do anybody have better ideas how this could be achieved in a more AJAX way rather than a brute block function?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) does a great job of explaining the basics. While many browsers are now supporting them natively (besides IE), you'll still want to include a polyfill like [es-6 promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise). Once you start using promises you can solve your issues doing things like this:

```
var a = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'example.com/test/1',
        success: function(response){resolve(response);},
        error: function(response){reject(response);}
    });
});

var b = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'example.com/test/1',
        success: function(response){resolve(response);},
        error: function(response){reject(response);}
    });
});

var c = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'example.com/test/1',
        success: function(response){resolve(response);},
        error: function(response){reject(response);}
    });
});

//This will run once all async operations have successfully finished
Promise.all([a,b,c]).then(
    function(data){
        //everything successful, handle data here
        displayData(data);
    },
    function(data){
        //something failed, handle error here
        logoutError(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Only for information purposes: this is not supported by any IE, even 11 - http://caniuse.com/#search=promise

Comment: But IE problem can be resolved by using [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) as mentioned in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks Victor! I just edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Neat. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try event based approach. Put methods `a()`, `b()` and `c()` in a class and on done of each check if all three are done and if done then raise an event which will be captured by listener and then it can execute `d()`

<strike>I will try to demo this using code.</strike>

Comment: In other words: Put d() in the done() of a, b and c following a check of aFinished&&bFinished&&cFinished. And d() will be fired by the last completed one. Am I getting you correctly? Very smart way indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Move the check into d() and call in an `done(..)` (unless you want it to happen on regardless of whether it was successful or not - in which case use `always(..)`) of a, b and c

```
var aFinished=false;
function a() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller:'environment', action:'a')}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true
      }).done(function(jsonData) {
          //do something
          aFinished=true;
          d();
      });
}
//same flag+function for b() and c()
function d(){
    if(aFinished&&bFinished&&cFinished){
        var jsonData=$.ajax(...).done(...);
    }
}

a();b();c();
```

Then there is no need for your `blockTillAllDone` or the `setTimeout`

Comment: This is actually same as proposed by @ndd. Fast and smart solution indeed. But honestly I'm just curious whether AJAX can provide a way like $.whenConditionMet({...}).ajax({...}).